# Not able to uncheck a radiobutton after selecting another

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

Here is my setup: If `radiobutton1` is already checked when the page loads (it has `checked="checked"` in view source) and I try to uncheck it after selecting `radiobutton2`, the `checked` attribute on `radiobutton1` is not getting removed after selecting `radiobutton2`:

```
if($('#' + radiobutton1_ID).is(':checked'))
    UncheckRadioButton('#' + radiobutton2_ID);

// Utility function to clear a radiobutton's "checked" attribute
function UncheckRadioButton(radiobuttonID) {
    radiobuttonID.removeAttr("checked"); 
}
```

After selecting `radiobutton2` and doing a "View Source" I see no `checked="checked"` on `radiobutton2` (**even though the page shows this button as checked**), and for `radiobutton1` it still shows `checked="checked"`. Why is that? It should be the other way around.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is some more of my code.  I know that the `if` statement portions are getting hit so that's not the issue, and I know the radio button IDs (`ccRadioBtn`, `checkRadioBtn` and `paypalRadioButton`) I am using are correct:

```
    var ccRadioBtn = ccRadioButton; // credit card radio button ID
    var paypalRadioButton = payPalRadioClientID;

    // ...

    if (paypalIsSelected()) {
        UncheckRadioButton(checkRadioBtn);
        UncheckRadioButton(ccRadioBtn);

        // ...
    } else {
        // force a clear on any previously selected payment options
        CheckRadioButton(ccRadioBtn); // default to credit card radio button
        UncheckRadioButton(paypalRadioButton);
        UncheckRadioButton(checkRadioBtn);

        // ...
    }
}

function UncheckRadioButton(radiobuttonID) {
    $('#' + radiobuttonID).removeAttr("checked"); 
}

function CheckRadioButton(radiobuttonID) {
    $('#' + radiobuttonID).attr('checked', true);
}
```

The problem is: If one radio button defaults to `checked="checked"` and I click another radio button, the first radio button's `checked` attribute should be removed but it's not. And the second radio button that has been selected has no `checked="checked"` as it should. I can see this when I view the page source.  I am not sure why that is not working.

Comment: I've updated my post with my actual code.  Problem still exists.

Comment: the problem ended up not being a JS issue but I did get a lot out of this thread.  Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a string here:

```
UncheckRadioButton('#' + radiobutton_2_ID);
```

But trying to use it as a jQuery object here:

```
radiobuttonID.removeAttr("checked");
//which is actually doing this:
"#something".removeAttr("checked"); //.removeAttr() is not a function for string
```

You need to wrap it to use it as a selector, like this:

```
$(radiobuttonID).removeAttr("checked");
```

As for the view source...it depends in the browser, IE for example will show the *original* source of the page, not the state you're currently viewing.

Comment: It still isn't working.  I don't know why but again if I select radiobutton1, view source it has checked="checked" as expected.  But after I change and select radiobutton2 and then view source, radiobutton1 still has checked="checked" and radiobutton2 has no checked attribute at all.  Is there just something I don't know about the DOM here?  Maybe the view source doesn't represent the current state?  Meaning if I change to radiobutton2 after radiobutton1 the state isn't realized until a postback?

Comment: @coffeeaddict - Is the UI checked, just not the view source? also which browser are you using?  You should use Chrome or Firebug and inspect element for this to get an accurate *current* view.

Comment: when you say UI checked, the radio button is selected yes.  When the page loads I set the paypal radio button to be checked by default (using .NET code / code-behind).  Then I click and change to the credit card radio button on the UI.  Then I view source to see if the radio button for paypal had it's checked="checked" removed and a checked="checked" added to the credit card radio button since it naturally should since I selected the cc radio button right?  The view source should now show the cc radio button with checked="checked" right?